# Memory management patterns

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory-management, raii

I'd like to know about other patterns that could be more efficient than the use of factories.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "more efficient than factories". Usually factories serve you as a programmer to better keep track of allocations, indexing and deletions of objects. So if something more efficient existed, you could pack that into a factory as well. I'm also wondering.. how large is your memory consumption actually? And how much time do you actually safe with recycling instead of deleting and allocating? Have you done benchmarks?

Comment: See C++ Allocator concept and/or memory pools - for example, `std::vector` class template can be provided with an allocator that controls the way memory is allocated - that way the user can control the allocation policy on his own. You can provide similar mechanism in your library.

Comment: You could have the factories just create objects handled by shared smart pointers. Taking those from pools of specific sizes would help you to control memory consumption. In case of reaching the limit you can grow the pool or throw an exception.

Comment: @Imad Because the client and the pool store pointers to the objects. Using smart pointer allows to safely shrink the pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a memory pool, the boost one is pretty good:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool.html

And every client could configure the maximum size of the pool.
Allocations and deallocations will be really fast,and you will drop your factory implementation

Answer (score 2):

Measure first. If you haven't proved that your allocator is a performance problem then you shouldn't optimize it away. Your solution to not free memory back may in fact perform worse (e.g., if you're using a simple free-list, you might be spending a lot of time on cache misses when you traverse the list).

If memory allocation is a bottleneck, look into better allocators. TCMalloc is pretty good, and there are commercial and cross-platform solutions available if you want to pay lots of money.

But use a profiler and measure before you do anything drastic.